# Which version is more compatible for me? 14 or 16?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, 17.10

I am using Hp Compaq 8510w model computer with 3 gigabytes of RAM and 2.5 Ghz of CPU, 65 bit.

I was using 17.10th version of Ubuntu. Even though my computer is suitable with 17.10th requirements, my expierence was not quite smooth.

I want a smooth experience of Ubuntu. I decieded to use a older version of Ubuntu, I tried 10.04 but it was outdated, literally died. I want to try 16.04.4 and my system looks suitable with 16.04.

However, after my failure with 17.10, I still want to ask, should I use 16 or 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for 14.04 will end next year, I would not recommend to go for it any more.

What is far more important regarding performance and requirements, rather than the version of Ubuntu, is the desktop environment you use. 17.10 uses Gnome, 16.04 uses Unity. Both are not the most lightweight environments, so maybe try Xubuntu (XFCE desktop) or Lubuntu (LXDE desktop) instead of plain Ubuntu.

Regarding versions, I'd definitely going for 16.04 if you want an LTS (Long Term Support) release that is very stable and supported until 2021, or 17.10 if you want the latest Ubuntu version with more recent software versions, but only support until July 2018. The next release, 18.04, is going to be officially released in April and will be supported for the next five years, but is currently still in beta.

Comment: You helped me a lot! I do not want to use any of the lighter versions, I would use my other computer and use ubuntu on it but i would not ever ever use lubuntu, xubuntu or any of lighter ubuntu versions. I will try my chances with 16.04 LTS, thanks.